# Comparing elements of a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big list that looks something like this (but way bigger)

```
lista = [(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]))]
```

You can't see it in the little extract I put but there are some elements that repeat. I need for the duplicates to go away.

I have tried doing

```
newlist = []
for a in lista:
    if np.all(a not in newlist):
         newlist.append(a)
```

But it doesnt work and it returns

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Don't understand why it doesn't work. Need to compare each element on my list as the list of arrays they are.

edit: a duplicate can be any element of the list. It's a duplicate if one element, a tuple, shares the exact same arrays, in the same order, as another tuple.

```
(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]))
```

Comment: Are the duplicate elements arrays in themselves, or elements inside the main list?

Comment: a duplicate would be this for example `(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]))`

Comment: It's still unclear what you define as "duplicates". Do you wish to remove duplicate arrays for each tuple inside your list? or remove duplicated arrays across all tuples in your list?

Comment: With duplicates I mean duplicates of the elements of the main list. Those elements are a tuple composed of 3 arrays. So I want to get rid of the duplicate tuples containing the same arrays inside.

Comment: your example contains zero duplicate tuples though

Comment: Wait, you mean a duplicate is a tuple that contains identical arrays like the example in your comment above?

Comment: Yeap, that's a duplicate. I said it doesnt contain any duplicates, since they start appearing like in the element 18 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of a duplicate: a tuple with exactly the same arrays repeated in the list.

```
import numpy as np

# list with the 5th tuple being a duplicate of the 1st
lista = [(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
         (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
         (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
         (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
         (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
         (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
         (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]))]

clean_list = []

for t in lista:
    for ut in clean_list:
        if all(np.all(t[i] == ut[i]) for i in range(len(t)))):
            # duplicate, discard it
            break
    else:
        # does not exist, keep it
        clean_list.append(t)
```

The result `clean_list` will contain all tuples except the 5th tuple which is a duplicate of the 1st.

Note that this example uses Python's built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function for checking the truth of all conditions passed to it and [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) for checking the equality of all elements in the compared arrays.

Comment: I don't understand what it is doing, but it's working half way. it's deleting more elements than it should. Like an element that exists is `([ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 1.])` but  `([ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 2.])` also exists, and it's keeping only the one with the highest number (it should keep both).

Comment: It removes only tuples which contain exactly equal arrays. Please update your question with examples of the current output vs the actual output you want.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, had to adjust a loop that existed for it to work (the loop created `lista` that's why it needed to be changed). It works, the problem is it's deleting the tuple that contains all zeros arrays.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? The example you provide after your edit in the OP is exactly that, a tuple with 3 zero arrays.

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate but it deletes all of them, not just the duplicates. For that one case of all zeros though, for the rest it works great.

Comment: Then it's still not clear what your definition of a duplicate is. Please post an example of the expected output.

Comment: a duplicate element can be any of them. It's a duplicate if it repeats again. Another example is `([ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 1.])` it also repeats itself after a while. If an element, which is a tuple, shares the three arrays with another tuple in the list then it's a duplicate.

Comment: That's what I asked in the comments and your response was absolutely something different. Does the order of the arrays in the tuple matter, that is would you consider (1, 2, 3) equal to (2, 1, 3)?

Comment: Yes, the order matters

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure you are using the method "all" properly, though I am not familiar with it. Here's a reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html

Couldn't you just do?:

```
newlist = []
for a in lista:
    if a not in newlist:
         newlist.append(a)
```

Comment: I get the same error if I put that code. Since the error says it has to do with `.all()` or `.any()`, thought that by adding it that way it would fix it, but it doesn't.

Comment: Just updated my post, do you need to keep the arrays?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep all the elements as they are (a list of arrays), only delete the duplicates. I ran that code and it still doesnt work.

Comment: I reverted back that edit. It works for me when I use: `lista = [([ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  0.]),
 ([ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  1.]),([ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  0.])]`  I am not quite sure I know what you mean. Is a duplicate, if all arrays in a tuple is the same?

Comment: @Ben He's using numpy arrays not normal Python lists which is a completely different thing.

Comment: I haven't got numpy, I am just using the list to 'simulate' it. After all both are objects containing items. Shouldn't the above code work for both, as a tuple of array objects existing in a list acts like a tuple of lists existing in a list.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `in`, python iterates the list and checks for equality with your element. However, equality check will yield something like `[True, False, True]`, which is neither true none false. So you can't use the `in` operator, but you can simulate it with the check below

```
newlist = []

for line in lista:
    for item in line:
        if not any(all(item == value) for value in newlist):
            newlist.append(item)
```

Essentially, with `all(item==value) for value in list)` you're simulating the behavior of `in`, and with `not any`, you ask that none of the checks should be true/

Comment: It works for deleting stuff, but it doesn't work to what I need. The elements of `lista` are a tuple consisting of 3 arrays, and they should keep that structure. So a duplicate of an element is basically a tuple containing the same 3 arrays in the same order than another one. I'll study your code and see if I can change it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
from numpy import array

lista = [(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.])),
 (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])),
 (array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]))]

y = []

for a in lista:
    found = 0
    for b in y:
        if found >= 3:
            break
        found = 0
        for i in range(0,3):
            if False in numpy.in1d(a[i], b[i]):
                break
            found += 1
    if found < 3:
        y.append(a)

for a in y:
    print a
```

The code goes through each of the elements in the list and compares the elements to the tuples using `numpy.in1d(a, b)`. If the 3 elements match consequently, the item is a duplicate. Otherwise, it's added to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all rows have equal length, the following will solve your problem:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.unique(lista)
```

Comment: This will work on a single element dimension and not the tuples (1d), thus it will output `[0. 1.]` instead of the unique tuples.